# Python right position for a Error message in a class

Tags: python, optimization

first of all sorry for this easy question. I have a class

```
class Grid(object):
    __slots__= ("xMin","yMax","nx","ny","xDist","yDist","ncell","IDtiles")
    def __init__(self,xMin,yMax,nx,ny,xDist,yDist):
        self.xMin = xMin
        self.yMax = yMax
        self.nx = nx
        self.ny = ny
        self.xDist = xDist
        self.yDist= yDist
        self.ncell = nx*ny
        self.IDtiles = [j for j in np.ndindex(ny, nx)]
        if not isinstance(nx, int) or not isinstance(ny, int):
            raise TypeError("an integer is required for nx and ny")
```

where

```
xMin = minimum x coordinate (left border)
yMax = maximum y coordinate (top border)
nx = number of columns
ny = number of rows
xDist and yDist = resolution (e.g., 1 by 1)
```

nx and ny need to be an integer. I wish to ask where is the most elegant position for  the TypeError. Before all self. or in the end?

Comment: Ideally, you should write your whole Grid class and then show it to us. Then we'd suggest all the ways in which it could be improved rather then asking lots of specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Grid(object):
    __slots__= ("xMin","yMax","nx","ny","xDist","yDist","ncell","IDtiles")
    def __init__(self,xMin,yMax,nx,ny,xDist,yDist):
```

Python convention says that argument should be lowercase_with_underscores

```
        self.xMin = xMin
        self.yMax = yMax
```

The same convention holds for your object attributes

```
        self.nx = nx
        self.ny = ny
        self.xDist = xDist
        self.yDist= yDist
        self.ncell = nx*ny
        self.IDtiles = [j for j in np.ndindex(ny, nx)]
```

This is the same as `self.IDtiles = list(np.ndindex(ny,nx))`

```
        if not isinstance(nx, int) or not isinstance(ny, int):
            raise TypeError("an integer is required for nx and ny")
```

This would be more conventialy put at the top. But in python we prefer duck typing, and don't check types. You shouldn't really be checking the types are correct. Just trust that the user of the class will pass the right type or something close enough.

Comment: Thanks @Winston Ewert. I didn't get about "duck typing". Do you suggest to avoid the "TypeError"? and the argument should be lowercase_with_underscores do you intend example self.__xMin = xMin?

Comment: @Gianni, xMin should be x_min. There should be no capital letters in your names. Basically, only class names are named using capital letters. Re: duck typing. Just don't throw the TypeError. The python convention is to not check the types and just allow exceptions to be thrown when the type is used in an invalid manner.

Comment: Thank Winston really useful post for me. I have just the last question to clarify my doubts. inside a class if i have a function def get_distance_to_origin(xPoint,yPoint):
#do some stuff (es euclidean distance). Do i need to write x_point and y_point in order to respect the style?

Comment: @Gianni, yes, that is correct